# .htaccess redirect with php slug

Tags: .htaccess, url-rewriting, slug

My rewrite code is:

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} ^[A-Z]{3,9}\ /(.*)index\.php($|\ |\?)
RewriteRule ^ /%1 [R=301,L]

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME}.php -f
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ $1.php [NC,L]    

RewriteRule ^products/([a-z0-9_-]+)$ products.php?slug=$1
```

But, this shows and internal server error for the products/`slugname` rewrite rule.

I've only used small letter, numbers and dash(-) in my slug id.

Comment: Any other rules in htaccess?

Comment: When I create an _empty folder_  **products** in the root it seems to work, is it supposed to work that way?

Comment: yes they are, and the rewrite rule for hiding the exension was causing this probem. Is there a way i can use both in the same .htaccess file

Comment: how is your files structure? /foo/index.php or /foo.php?

Comment: its **/filename.php**

Answer (score 0):

Try this :

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} /([^.]+)\.php [NC]
RewriteRule ^ /%1 [R,L]

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME}.php -f
RewriteRule ^([^/]+)/?$ /$1.php [NC,L]    

RewriteRule ^products/([a-z0-9_-]+)$ /products.php?slug=$1 [NC,L]
```

Comment: Is your htaccess in root?

Comment: yes it is in the root folder, except for hiding _index.php_ in the url for the index file, everything else failed to work. But, I do appreciate your help bro.